# Rails: Store JSON in MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, mongomapper

I am getting multiple similar JSON object from a remote site and looking to store them in a local MongoDB.

What would be the best way to do this ? (Preferably via Mongoid or Mongo-mapper gems)

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use a mongoid field of type Hash or an embedded document.

```
class MyModel
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :some_data, :type => Hash
end
```

Comment: For latest releases: field :some_data, type: Hash

Answer (score 12):

If you just want store your JSON in Mongo you don't need Mongoid or MongoMapper. Just use the Mongo-ruby-driver

```
require 'mongo'

db   = Mongo::Connection.new.db('sample-db')
coll = db.collection('test')
coll.insert(ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(you_json))
```

With that you store in database sample-db in collection test

Answer (score 1):

Found out I can just put data directly into mongoid without defining the fields:

`SomeMongoidObject['dynamic_attribute'] = json_data`

Comment: Nice workaround, but I would still like to see mongoid supporting JSON fields as an option.

Comment: I have logged this as an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1603

Comment: Got feedback on the issue. Apparently you can just use field type Hash or embedded document. Have posted an answer as such here.